# How do I load multiple buttons in at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-button

I wanted to avoid answering this question and figure it out myself but after an entire afternoon wasted, here I am. I am trying to load 3 buttons when my app starts up. I tried using multiple startActivities but only one would load at a time and I am not sure why. I also tried using AsyncTasks but they seemed overly complex for what I was trying to do. For example, one of buttons was going to open the Google Maps application. I already have the code and had that working but I want one button that does that and 2 other buttons that do different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to use an AsyncTask like this:

When you click the button it will execute the AsyncTask:

```
public void ThirtySecVideoPlayer(){
    ThirtySecondImageButton =     (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ThirtySecAdImageButton);
    ThirtySecondImageButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String Category = "Cleaninig";

                    String ProductUploadMethod = "ProductUploadMethod";
                    ProductUpload ProductUpload = new ProductUpload();
                    ProductUpload.execute(ProductUploadMethod, Category);
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Then in your AsyncTask you get the params and us it in the AsyncTask:

```
    private class ProductUpload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String Category = params[1];

    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result){

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate (Void...values){
        }
}
```

You can use the button code for each button and then call the same AsyncTask, but you need to make sure that the variable category executes the correct code in the DoInBackround with an If statement!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the button dynamically in your onCreate method.

```
// this is the text to put in the created button
String[] btnText = ["Button 1", "Button 2","Button 3"];
// the ID allows to determine witch button was pressed
int btnID = 0;
// in the for web be created the 3 button dynamically
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
final Button Btn = new Button(this);
Btn.setText(btnText[]);

//This is to give the button the size he need to wrap the text in it
LinearLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.wrap_content, LayoutParams.wrap_content);
Btn.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams);

Btn.setId(btnID);

btnID ++;

Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

//This returns the Id of the clicked button
// the Id of each button was set by the  "Btn.setId(btnID);"
DetectclickedButton(Btn.getId());
    }); 
}

public void DetectclickedButton(id){

switch(id){
case 1:
// Do something in the click of the 1 button
break;
case 2:
// Do something in the click of the 2 button
break;
case 3:
// Do something in the click of the 3 button
break;
}

}
```